# Remove back arrow in sherlockactionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

[image]

I need to remove the back arrow and keep only the home icon in action bar sherlock library. I set `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` to `false` but it disabled action bar button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the home button itself as enabled?

Try this instead:

```
    // Hide the ActionBar's up button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```